# Error: No named parameter withthe name title: Text( in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class BottomNavBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarWidgetState createState() => _BottomNavBarWidgetState();
}

class _BottomNavBarWidgetState extends State<BottomNavBarWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
//        navigateToScreens(index);
      });
    }

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2c2b2b)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFfd5352),
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }
}
```

I was assigned to run a mobile application with the Flutter framework. But I don't understand how to use "title" in the navbar item, of course with style. Therefore, I want to ask, "How do I fix the error in the code?" and how to include a proper "title" parameter in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining the `title` on `BottomNavigationBarItem` because it doesn't exist anymore, you should use the `label` which accepts a `String`, like this:

```
// ... 
BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home', // use this
        ),
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In updated flutter version `title` is migrated with `label`.

Use it like :

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` parameter is deprecated by the flutter, either use a **previous flutter** version or change your title parameter to `label` which accepts only `string` as a parameter.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: const Text('Home') // remove this and replace it with
          label: 'Home', // this instead...
        ),
```

For styling the text use customized theme in material app for example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(), // edit this object
      home: const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```